# IntelliJ2-IDEA get Maven-2 to download source and documentation

Tags: maven-2, intellij-idea

I have a spring mvc project setup using maven in IntelliJ.
While I was setting the project up, IntelliJ asked me if I wanted to download the source and documentation. In order to save time at that point I did not select this option. However now I would like to download some of the source if not all. Does any one know where how to accomplish this in IntelliJ for a project that has already been setup?

The question is specific to how to do this with intelliJ since I would like all the mouse over and documentation features in IntelliJ to show me the source / documentation when needed.

Thanks,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For automatic downloading: Go to File --> Settings --> Maven --> Importing. Then check the automatic download options.

To do so once only, open the Maven tab and click on the download icon and select "Download Sources and Documentation"

Comment: This works, causes all the Maven-controlled libraries to have their source and/or documentation downloaded automatically.. But isn’t there also a way to manually invoke Maven within IntelliJ to download source or documentation for one specific library?