# IntelliJ steps through the wrong lines when debugging remote Java application

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, remote-debugging, liquibase

I tried to remote debug a maven plugin for a [liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) project with Intellij. IDEA is highlighting the wrong source code line.
I manually built and installed the plugin in my local maven repository from sources in my Intellij project. Intellij version is `11.1.3` and maven version is `3.0.4` running on Ubuntu 12.04.

For debugging the maven plugin I used `mvnDebug` comand.
If someone has any ideas please give me some advice. I'm not too used to remote debugging (in fact this is the second time I've done this).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For me, whenever IntelliJ is highlighting the wrong line, it was always because the version of the JAR/classes being used to run the application differs from my source files - i.e. different version of the sources were used to build the JAR and/or classes.

You are going to have to be sure that you are working from the exact source that was used to build the classes you are debugging.

You can verify this by looking at the classpath being used to launch the application, locating the JAR file or classes directory that contains the classes you are debugging, and verifying that they were built from the sources you are inspecting.

Note that when you are debugging third-party libraries, you often can download the "sources" jar (see [IntelliJ2-IDEA get Maven-2 to download source and documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572500/intellij2-idea-get-maven-2-to-download-source-and-documentation)).

Comment: Thank you guy's! In my case, plugin version used to build the project wasn't the same with the sources that I was trying to debug. It was a dummy thing for me to not check what plugin version is used when the project is build. I thought it will use my manually build version.

Answer (score 3):

If you stumbled across this post, and sure that the source and JAR are the same code, then this could be your problem.

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-8021

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing remote debugging you can run the plugin directly from IntelliJ.

1. Have the liquibase plugin project loaded in IntelliJ by just pointing at the `pom.xml`.
2. Choose `Edit Configurations...`
3. Press the <kbd>+</kbd> button to `Add New Configuration`.
4. Select `Maven`.
   [image]
5. Enter the `Working directory` to the project you want to run the plugin on.
6. Enter the `Command line`. Could be `process-sources`, `compile` or `liquibase:status` depending on what you want to do.
7. Press <kbd>OK</kbd>
8. Set a breakpoint in the Liquibase Mojo.

Now you can start this configuration by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>.

Maven will start and finally you will see that your plugin is waiting at the breakpoint!

---

Make sure that you have defined the plugin in the target `pom.xml` with correct version and also that you build the plugin before launching it. You can ensure that by enabling `Make` in the `Before Launch` pane.

[image]

Comment: It works very well. Simple and fast, although remote-debugging is quite speedy when everything is on your local machine.

Comment: I guess it depends on the situation. If you are developing a plugin then this approach has better turn-around time. But in your case when you are using an already developed plugin then the other solution might be better.